# Critical points in multivariable calc

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the critical points of

$z = x^{3} + 3xy^{2} - 3x^{2} - 3y^{2} + 7$

I understand if it was $f(x,y)$ but this z is really throwing me off..

I could take the partial derivs of x and y, but if I take the partial of z I get 0=0?

EDIT after comment. Ok, so I will take the partial derivatives.

$Fx = 3x^{2} + 3y^{2} - 6x$

|

$Fy = 6xy - 6y$

Where would I go from here in obtaining the critical points.. solve for x and y @ 0?

Comment: Then think of it as $f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2-3x^2-3y^2+7$. It's exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let the $z$ confuse you. It's in the same spirit as denoting $y=f(x)$ for some function of one variable. In single variable calculus, if we have some polynomial like
$$
y=f(x)= x^3 - 2x + 3
$$
then we can either write
$$
f'(x) = 3x^2 - 2
$$
or
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2 - 2.
$$
Likewise, if we want to take the partial derivatives of $z=f(x, y) = x^3 + 3xy^2 - 3x^2 - 3y^2 +7$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, we can write
$$
f_x(x, y) = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 3x^2 + 3y^2 - 6x
$$
$$
f_y(x, y) = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -6y + 6xy.
$$
To find the critical points of $f$, simply find the points $(x, y)$ where $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$.

Comment: Ok, ok, I have found multiple points, [2,0],[0,0],[1,1],[1,-1], all of these would then be considered critical points? Thanks!

Comment: Yep! That's all of them, I think.